# Need help comparing switch cases to make sure cards picked aren't identical

Tags: c++, blackjack

I'm trying to write a c++ program for a single-player blackjack but i'm not sure how to make sure that none of the cards drawn are identical. I used case switch method to draw 2 random cards but I'm not sure how to make it choose 2 different cards.

```
int player_card1 = rand() % 13 + 1;     //player card 1
int player_card2 = rand() % 13 + 1;  //player card 2
    int value = 0;
cout << "Current Hand: ";
switch (player_card1) {
    case 10: cout << "A-";
        value+=10;
        break;
    case 11: cout << "J-";
        value+=10;

        break;
    case 12: cout << "Q-";
        value+=10;

        break;
    case 13: cout << "K-";
        value+=10;

        break;
    default: cout << player_card1 << "-";
        value+=player_card1;

        break;
}
switch (player_card2) {
    case 10: cout << "A";
        value+=10;
        cout << " with a value of " << value;
        break;
    case 11: cout << "J";
        value+=10;
        cout << " with a value of " << value;

        break;
    case 12: cout << "Q";
        value+=10;
        cout << " with a value of " << value;

        break;
    case 13: cout << "K";
        value+=10;
        cout << " with a value of " << value;

        break;
    default: cout << player_card2;
        value+=player_card2;
        cout << " with a value of " << value;

        break;
}
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the best method is to create a `Deck` of `Cards`.  Let each player be a *hand* or `std::vector<Card>`.  When dealing out a `Card`, remove it from the `Deck` and append to the player's `Hand`.  This will insure that there are no duplicates in the player's hand.  Also, you can use `std::shuffle` on the `Deck` to randomize the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the first card as you do:

```
int player_card1 = rand() % 13 + 1;     //player card 1
```

And then continue to attempt to draw a second card until you get one that's different from the first:

```
int player_card2 = rand() % 13 + 1;
//Keep drawing until we get a different card from player 1
while(player_card2 == player_card1) { player_card2 = rand() % 13 + 1; }
```

Or if you want to be a little fancier:

```
int player_card2;
while( (player_card2 = rand() % 13 + 1) == player_card1 ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a container of cards and deal the cards to the player.  Randomize the container of cards.  When dealing cards, remove them from the container.  This will ensure no duplicates are drawn.

### Math, no glamour

There are 52 cards in the deck.
If we number the cards from 0 to 51, we can use some math to determine the card:

```
Card suit == (card number / 13)
```

So, you can map the suit number, e.g. 0:Spades, 1:Hearts, 2:Clubs, 3: Diamonds.

```
Card Value == (card number) % 13
```

The deck can be a vector of integers:

```
std::vector<int> deck(52);
```

Initializing the deck:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
{
    deck[i] = i;
}
std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
```

Let's use `std::vector` as the player's hand:

```
std::vector<int> players_hand;
```

Dealing to the player requires moving a card from the deck to the player's hand:

```
players_hand.push_back(deck[0]);
players_hand.push_back(deck[1]);
deck.erase(deck.begin(), deck.begin() + 2);
```

The player's hand can be displayed in a more readable fashion by using the math (above).

### Structures for Readability

The above algorithm can be augmented by representing a card as a `struct`.

```
enum class Card_Suit : int {SUIT_SPADES, SUIT_HEARTS, SUIT_CLUBS, SUIT_DIAMONDS};

struct Card
{
    enum Card_Suit suit;
    int            face_value;
};
```

You'll need to expand the `Card` class with methods for input and output and maybe add some useful methods (such as adding face values).

You can convert the `Card_Suit` to text using a `std::map`:

```
std::map<enum Card_Suit, std::string> Suite_To_Text;
Suite_To_Text[SUIT_SPADES] = "Spade";
// ... etc. ...
Card c = players_hand[0];
cout << c.face_value << ' ' << Suite_To_Text[c.suit] << "\n";
```